# Attribute of argument class

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I have a base class and derived classes. The derived one contains vector of objects and derived_two contains vector of strings. I am pushing objects to deriver_one vector and strings to derived_two vector.

```
class Base{
   public:
       virtual void Greetings(){ cout << " I am base class " << endl;}
       virtual string getName(){ return "base";}
       virtual vector<string>* getStr() { return NULL; }
       virtual bool operator == (Base *);
};
class Derived_one : public Base{
   public:
       virtual void Greetings(){ cout << " I am derived one " << endl;}
       virtual string getName(){ return "one";}
       virtual bool operator == (Base *);
   private:
  vector<Base*> m;
};
class Derived_two : public Base{
   public:
      virtual void Greetings(){ cout << " I am derived two " << endl;}
      virtual string getName(){ return "two";}
      virtual vector<string>* getStr() { return &str; }
   private:
  vector<string> str;
};
```

However i would like to compare two instances of derived classes , i defined

```
bool Derived_one:: operator ==( Base *a ){
  for( size_t i = 0; i < m.size(); i++){
      if( m[i] -> getStr() ){
        for( unsigned int j = 0; j < m[i] -> getStr() ->size(); j++){
          if((*(m[i] -> getStr()))[j] != a -> (*(m[i] -> getStr()))[j] ){
              return false;
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token|
```

the error reffers to line

```
if((*(m[i] -> getStr()))[j] != a -> (*(m[i] -> getStr()))[j]
```

Why does compiler complains here? The `getStr()` return pointer to vector , that will get dereferenced by * . The a as argument is pointer type here. Whats is the root of problem here? I fail to find any answer to this.
Thanks

Comment: Which line does the error refer to ?

Comment: if((*(m[i] -> getStr()))[j] != a -> (*(m[i] -> getStr()))[j]

Comment: `a->(*(m[i] -> getStr()))[j]` is indeed syntactically invalid : to the right of `->` should be the name of a member of `*a`. What are you trying to express ?

Comment: You have over a dozen subexpressions there. Split them out into separate statements, to figure out which causes the error.

Comment: Since this is obviously not the RealCode™ (synax errors and typos galore) and the error message complains about a token not present in the posted code a) I don't understand the six upvotes (yet) and b) how are we supposed to know what is going on in your real code, i.e. what is part of the real problem and what is due to the dumbed-down version here?

Comment: Shouldn't `operator ==` take `Base&`?

Comment: BTW, I just copied your code into an IDE, and it's full of typos!!! You need to show a little bit more effort IMO (that is, if you're expecting others to make an effort for you).

Comment: I don't understand the 6 upvotes... this is a just a "look at me I put 4 lines of code in only one line!" ... Coding is also about presenting, and this is awful presentation. It is sometimes better to code 4 lines than having 1 line like this...

Comment: @barak manos i fixed the code , didnt notice those typos , sorry

Comment: Why did your compiler not notice them?

Answer (score 3):

The part of your expression `a->(*(m[i] -> getStr()))[j]` is invalid, the right hand side of `->` should be some kind of name.

I am guessing what you want is (*(a->m[i] -> getStr()))[j]

Though that would also be an error, as `Base` contains no member `m`, perhaps you want to case `a` to a `Derived_one*` e.g. `(*(dynamic_cast<Derived_one*>(a)->m[i] -> getStr()))[j]` ?

Thou this will not work if `a` does not point to a `Derived_one` object.
You can check this before hand, like so `typeid(Derived_one) == typeid(*a)`; (though that will fail if `*a` derives from, `Derived_one` (I'm not sure how to fix this).

You also have a typo `j <m[i]->getstr()` should be `j <m[i]->getStr()`
Your code may not return a value (if your `return false` statement is never hit), this is undefined behaviour, I suggest adding a `return true` statement to the end of your function.

You probably also wan't the argument to an `==` operator to be a const-reference not a pointer.
Making these changes will yield this code:

```
bool Derived_one:: operator ==(const Base& a) {
    if (typeid(Derived_one) != typeid(a))
        return false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        if (m[i]->getStr()) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j <m[i]->getStr()->size(); j++) {
                if ((*(m[i]->getStr()))[j] != (*(dynamic_cast<const Derived_one&>(a).m[i]->getStr()))[j]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Using this compiler wont complain , but when i try to compare two instances e.g (a == b ) , compiler complains about "no match for operator =="  like the argument will stay Base and object slicing appears.

Comment: @trolkura I have updated my answer now, try my new code.

Comment: This works qute well for now , however when i try to compare size of two vectors it throws seg fault e.g  size_t first = properties.size();
        size_t two = a.getVec() -> size(); where getVec is same function as getStr() but instead of str it returns m

Comment: @tolkura, this is probably due to `getVec()` returning an invalid pointer, as you havn't shown your code for it I can't help. Is it overridden in `Derived_one` to return a valid pointer?

Comment: yes it is declared in Derived_one to return reference to m

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the multiple typos in your code (: instead of ;, lacking ; to end a line, getstr instead of getStr), what you need is just to dynamic cast `a` to a `Derived_one *` and control that the result is not null. That's the power of dynamic_cast: if the original pointer cannot be cast to the correct class, you just get a null so that you can test it. Your code could then become (assuming that what you wanted to test was `(*(m[i] -> getStr()))[j] != (*(b -> m[i] -> getStr()))[j]`):

```
bool Derived_one:: operator ==( Base *a ){
  Derived_one* b = dynamic_cast<Derived_one *>(a);
  if (b == nullptr) return false;   // no need to process further
  for( size_t i = 0; i < m.size(); i++){
      if( m[i] -> getStr() ){
        for( unsigned int j = 0; j <m[i] -> getstr() -> size(); j++){
          if((*(m[i] -> getStr()))[j] != (*(b -> m[i] -> getStr()))[j] ){
              return false;
          }
        }
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: THanks for answer ,  this altought throws error "no match for operand == "

Comment: @trolkura: This is the implementation. The operator has to be declared in class declaration: `class Derived_one : public Base{
   public: ... bool operator == (Base *a); ... };`

Comment: I indeed declared it in class and the error still occur